# How to subscribe for any changes in the model in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout-2.2.0.js. I have following object in knockout :

```
 function Person(name, age)
 {
   this.Name = ko.observable(name);
   this.Age = ko.observable(age);
 }


 var person = ko.observable(new Person("Tom", 23));
```

Now what i want is to put a subscript on person observable object like :

```
 person.subscribe(function(newValue){
 //here i want the notification whenever person object name or age change
 });
```

But this is not happening with the above subscription.Is there any other way to do, or i am doing something wrong?

**Edit**

I know that we can do this by applying individual subscription to each individual property but i am looking for the general subscription method ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not applied binding,use-`ko.applyBindings(new Person("Tom", 23));` and if you want some function should be called on change of your model then you should try 'custom binding' [Link here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // here you can call your function when some change occur in your observables
    }
};
```

Comment: the person is not top level model this the object in top level model

Comment: i dont know what you want but why you are not using custom binding if you need to call some function on value change ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin for this:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

And here's how you'd want to use it:

```
 person.watch(function(root, trigger){
     var newValue = trigger();
 });
```